# How to validate the form and uploaded file at the same time in Codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I am having a form that contains both an uploaded file and some other information. I want to validate the form information and the file at the same time when I hit submit. However, from the documentation, I can't find a way to do this. CI is suggesting to do the entire process in 3 steps:

1. Run the form validator, show errors
2. If it passed, process the upload, show errors
3. If the upload processed, write to the DB

Instead of writing my own method to validate the uploaded file's security, is that possible to use CI's existing library (combine form validation class and file validation class together) to finish the submission in one step.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('code', 'Code', 'trim|required');
if (empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
{
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'Document', 'required');
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't provide any security check. This is why I really want to use CI's upload class, so I don't have to write my own validation rules